# DataGridView check if any row selected and it's not NewRow

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How to check whether user selected row in datagrid view and this row is not newrow?

I tried so far this but not working as should:

```vb
If Not IsNothing(Grid.CurrentRow) And Not Grid.CurrentRow.IsNewRow Then
End If
```

First statement seems to works ok but when it comes to second it always return false even if I select NewRow

Comment: Where do you use this code and in what way does it not do what it should?

Comment: @TimSchmelter this is under button click event. Second statement always returns false even if I select newRow.

Comment: The original post was tagged only by `VB.NET` But since the answer posted by me was in C# and it was accepted by @JimmyJimm I added C# tag also to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have selected new row, the `DataGridView` will changes the current row on its `OnValidating` method. So if you click on `Button` when you have selected new row, the row remains selected, but the current row will be changed to its previous row.

So instead of checking for current row, if you want to do this check in `Click` event of a `Button`, it's better check for `SelectedRows`:

**C#**

```cs
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1 &&
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    MessageBox.Show("New Row Selected");
```

**VB.NET**

```vb
If (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 1 AndAlso _
    DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex) Then
    MessageBox.Show("New Row Selected")
End If
```

**Note:** Your provided code in question, will work untill the control is focuded.